# AJAX appending results duplicates

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm developing a live search function in a Laravel application, but I'm having some problems because i'm getting duplicate appends, for example I type in "Andrew".

Every key I hit starting with "A" until "W", im appending the results over and over, so Andre creates 6 table rows, but I want it to be only one.

The second problem is that if I delete all the input, I'm trying to show my "initial_table", but that doesn't work.

I tried changing `$('#ajax').append(row);` from append to html, but then I have only one result no matter how many matches I get.

```
<table id="usertable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Tier</th>    
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Tier</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody id="ajax">
            {{-- search results here  --}}
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="initial_table">
          @foreach ($users as $user)
          <tr>
          <td><a href="/admin/user/{{$user->id}}">{{$user->username}}</a> </td> 
            <td>{{$user->tier}}</td>
          </tr>  
          @endforeach



        </tbody>
      </table>
```

This is my Javascript

```
<script>
});
// })
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("keyup", searchUsers);
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("change", searchUsers);

function searchUsers(){
    if(this.value != '') {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/searchUsers?search=' + this.value,
            method: 'GET'
        }).done(function(response){

            console.log(typeof response);
            console.log(response);
            if(response.length < 1) {
                $('#ajax').append('<span class="text-center">No results found!</span>'); 
                $('#initial_table').hide(); 
            }
            else {
                $.each(response, function(index, obj){
                var row = $('<tr>');
                    row.append('<td> <a href="/admin/user/' + obj.id + '">' + obj.username +  ' AJAX' + '</td>');
                    row.append('<td>' + obj.tier + '</td>');
                    $('#ajax').append(row);
                    $('#initial_table').hide();

            });
            }

        });
    }

}


</script>
```

Comment: Don't append each result, build the whole row contents and then replace them with `.html` at the end.

Comment: how about the initial state of the table?

Comment: Well, what *is* the initial state? I'm sure you have a query for that if you're showing something. Just run that thing again once search is empty.

Comment: this is the initial state : <tbody id="initial_table">
          foreach ($users as $user)
          <tr>
          <td><a href="/admin/user/{{$user->id}}">{{$user->username}}</a> </td> 
            <td>{{$user->tier}}</td>
          </tr>  
          endforeach



        </tbody>

Comment: define row as a global variable, before call the searchUsers function, like var row = ''; then use,  row = $('<tr>');
                    row.append('<td> <a href="/admin/user/' + obj.id + '">' + obj.username +  ' AJAX' + '</td>');
                    row.append('<td>' + obj.tier + '</td>');
                    $('#ajax').append(row);
                    $('#initial_table').hide();

Comment: @MdJuyelRana What exactly would be the reason behind using a global variable here and how would your solution fix OP's problem? Comments are not suitable for code, if you feel you have a viable solution to the problem, supply an answer.

Comment: I fetch this problem one of my project by using global variable I solve that, hope it will solve also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to add some comments to explain . Hope it helps

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("keyup", searchUsers);
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("change", searchUsers);

function searchUsers(){
    if((this.value.trim()) != '') // even for extra space it should not allow in
    {
        $.ajax({
                  url: '/admin/searchUsers?search=' + this.value,
                  method: 'GET'
          }).done(function(response)
          {

                console.log(typeof response);
                console.log(response);
                $('#ajax').empty();             //for 1st query :-on every ajax call it will first empty "#ajax" tbody 
                $('#initial_table').hide(); 

                if(response.length < 1) 
                {
                    $('#ajax').append('<span class="text-center">No results found!</span>'); 

                }
                else 
                {
                              $.each(response, function(index, obj)
                              {
                                        var row = $('<tr>');
                                        row.append('<td> <a href="/admin/user/' + obj.id + '">' + obj.username +  ' AJAX' + '</td>');
                                        row.append('<td>' + obj.tier + '</td>');
                                        $('#ajax').append(row);
                             });
                }

         });
    }else              // for 2nd query :- your code missing this part to show initial tbody if search text is all blank
    {
        $('#initial_table').show();
        $('#ajax').hide();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello! The code works, but it has a weird bug. The first search that i type works, but from the second search, the #ajax div keeps the display:none

Comment: I have fixed it by adding the following code:   if($("#ajax").is(":hidden")) {
                        $("#ajax").show();
                    }